# Borel measurability of a seemingly uncountable intersection

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

If $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, is the function $g: x \mapsto \sup \{ t \in \mathbb{R} : |x-f(t)| = \inf_{s}|x - f(s)| \}$ Borel measurable? I guess my problem is the uncountable intersection encountered in the equivalence $g(x) \leq c$ iff $|x - f(t)| \leq c$ for all $t$ minimizing $s \mapsto |x - f(s)|$. Intuitively it seems that $g$ should be Borel measurable.

Comment: At a glance, it seems you can use the continuity of $f$ to approximate everything well enough by rationals, so that really $g$ can be defined just in terms of quantification over $\mathbb{Q}$; then use the fact that if $S$ is a countable set, "$\forall u\in S$" and "$\exists u\in S$" correspond to countable intersections and unions respectively. But I don't have the time to carefully check that (hence the comment rather than answer).